# Laravel order by

Tags: php, laravel

Estou tendo problemas para ordenar dados que estão organizados da seguinte maneira:

```
1
1.1
2.2
2.2.1
2.2.1.1
10
11
```

O resultado que eu tenho é:

```
1
1.1
10
11
2.2
2.2.1
2.2.1.1
```

Para ordenar estou usando:

```
Schedule::where( 'construction_uuid', '=', $construction_uuid )->orderBy('eap', 'ASC')->get();
```

Qual seria a melhor solução para o meu problema?

Comment: Me parece que seu campo é do tipo texto e, portanto, a ordenação obtida é a esperada. Talvez você queira uma ordenação numérica e, neste caso, deverá transformar seu campo texto em um número. Atenção à quantidade de algarismos em cada nível. Outra possibilidade é, mesmo mantendo o campo texto, normalizar o tamanho dos números de cada nível (, '01.00.00.00', '01.01.00.00', ... '10.01.12.05').

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nesta modelagem você optou por armazenar o valor já formatado, o ideal seria usar o dado de forma semântica.

**Valor atual**

- 1.1
- 1.2.3
- 1.2.3.4

**O formato ideal para armazenar essa informação é:**

- 01001000
- 01002000
- 01002001
- 01002002
- 01002003

Utilize o formato "**AABBBCCCDDD**" com duas casas iniciais e subsequente de 3 cadas

A formatação dos dados você faz via código